# decoding an encrypted text

Tags: encryption, decode

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <fieldset id = 'bonobo_fieldset'>
                <label>Text eingeben:</label>
                <textarea id='input'></textarea><br>
                <button type="button" id="btn">Text verschlüsseln</button><br> <br>
                <p id='text'></p>


                <script>
                    var fieldset = document.getElementById('bonobo_fieldset');
                    var h4 = document.createElement('h4');
                    h4.innerHTML = '';
                    h4.textContent = '';
                    fieldset.appendChild(h4);
                    var btn = document.getElementById('btn');
                    btn.addEventListener('click', verschlüsseln);


                    var p_text = document.getElementById('text');

                    var Arr = new Array(
                            ['a', 1],
                            ['b', 2],
                            ['c', 3],
                            ['d', 4],
                            ['e', 5],
                            ['f', 6],
                            ['g', 7],
                            ['h', 8],
                            ['i', 9],
                            ['j', 10],
                            ['k', 11],
                            ['l', 12],
                            ['m', 13],
                            ['n', 14],
                            ['o', 15],
                            ['p', 16],
                            ['q', 17],
                            ['r', 18],
                            ['s', 19],
                            ['t', 20],
                            ['u', 21],
                            ['v', 22],
                            ['w', 23],
                            ['x', 24],
                            ['y', 25],
                            ['z', 26]
                            );


                    function verschlüsseln()
                    {
                        var input = document.getElementById('input').value;
                        input = input.toLowerCase
                        var rex = /[A-z]/;
                        for (i = 0; i < input.length; i++)
                        {
                            if (rex.test(input.charAt(i))) {
                                Arr.forEach(convert_to_number);
                                function convert_to_number(value) {
                                    console.log(input.charAt(i));
                                    console.log(value[0].toUpperCase());

                                    if (input.charAt(i) === value[0]) {
                                        input = input.replace(input.charAt(i), value[1]);
                                    }
                                }

                            }
                        }
                        document.getElementById('text').textContent = input;
                    }

                </script>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

So i´m still quite new to coding , and today i came up with this very simple encryption , the letters you put into the input textarea , simply become their index number in the Alphabet (1-26)
so for example (a = 1 , b = 2, c = 3, g = 7... and so on)

now since this encryption really is pretty simple and straight forward , i just cant think of a way to decode it , yet these are the things im interested the most in.

the problem is a = 1 , while j-s = 10-19. so how can i write a code , that lets the program decide on wether its an a , or a j-s?

thanks to anyone helping me out

wish you a good one!

Comment: Please use the correct terms, if something is encrypted you would have to decrypt it, if something is encoded you can decode it.  And actually it looks a lot more like encoding than encryption to me. You could use double digits for indices 1 to 9  i.e. 01 to 09.

Comment: thanks a lot , sorry as i said im new so i´m not familiar with most of the terminology, yet this solution would prevent the problem , but not solve it or?